# how does this ruby code work for setting configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see ruby code that looks like the following. It seems to be some sort of idiom for creating configuration or settings but I don't really understand it. Also, how would the `Application.configure` part of this code look?

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.something = foo
  config.....
  config....
  .
  config....
end
```

Comment: You know you can look at the source, right? :)

Comment: Yes but the rails source isn't exactly easy for a beginner like myself to look through. I'm also not sure if this is actual working code or just a sample I saw.

Comment: I haven't worked with Rails, so I can't say for sure, but it is probably executed in the scope of an `instance_eval` that defines a variable called `config`.

Comment: @Brand That's how Rails apps are configued; check out the files in the `config` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that configuration way is not specific to Ruby ; it's the applications (or libraries, gems) that choose to use it or not.

To explain you what does that code do, I'll take your snippet as an example:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.something = foo
end
```

Here, you are calling `MyApp::Application.configure` method, with no parameter. After the call, you're giving it a *block*.

You can think of blocks as a piece of code that you can use however you want.
They can be written in one single line or many:

```
{ puts 'hello' }
{ |param| puts param } # with passing it a param

# or 

do |param|
  puts param
end
```

(remember `my_array.each do ... end`? It's a block you pass it. ;) )

Now, that block would be called inside the `configure` method thanks to `yield`.

`yield` uses (or executes) the instructions of the block that has been passed to the method.

Example: Let's define a method with a yield inside of it:

```
def hello
  puts "Hello #{yield}"
end
```

If you call this method, you'd get a `'hello': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)'`.

You need to pass it a block: `hello { :Samy }`.
The result would then be `Hello Samy`. As you can see, it simply used what was in the block passed to the method.

That's exactly what's happening in the Rails configuration code. You simply set `config.something` (`config` is a method) to some value, and that same `config.something = foo` is execute inside `configure`.

You can learn more about `yield` and *blocks* [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm), and on this [great book](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9).

Answer (score 2):

The part from "do" until "end" is called a block, and is getting passed to the `configure` class method on `Application`. (all ruby methods can accept arguments and a block)

so the `Application.configure` method is creating a configuration object with a set of defaults, and then calling the block. The block is then setting the values you see, having the effect of overriding them.

It's then setting that configuration object as a class variable (like a global variable) so that other classes can use the configuration object later in the application lifecycle.

Hope that simplified description helps!